# doGet 関数を用いたスクリプトで日付のフォーマットを変更したい

Tags: google-apps-script

はじめまして、よろしくお願いいたします。

以下の記事を参考にして、`doGet` 関数を用いたスクリプトを書いております。

[【GASで作るワークフロー】URLクリックで「承認」とするスクリプトの作り方](https://tonari-it.com/gas-workflow-form-gmail-spreadsheet/)

以下のようにbodyで日付を引用すると、

```
body += `・購買日: ${date}\n`;
```

このような表示になってしまいます：

```
Mon Jul 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

スプレッドシート上では「13/07/20」と表示させているのですが、同じ様に、シンプルに表示する方法はありますでしょうか？

お力添えいただけましたら幸甚です。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 問題を引き起こすスクリプトが不明なため、これが直接の解決策かどうかわかりませんが、例えば、`getValues()`を使用して値を取得している場合、これを`getDisplayValues()`に変更すると、必要な結果を取得できますか？ [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) これに加えて、Web Appsを使用しているようであれば、スクリプトを変更した際はWeb Appsを新たなバージョンとして再デプロイしてください。これにより最新のスクリプトが反映されます。これにご注意ください。

Comment: Tanaike様、ご提示頂いたgetDisplayValues()に書き換えることで解決致しました！
嬉しいです！！ありがとうございます、感謝いたします！

Answer (score 0):

問題を引き起こすスクリプトが不明なため、直接の解決策となるかわかりませんが、例えば `getValues()` を使用して値を取得している場合、`getDisplayValues()`に変更すれば、必要な結果を取得できるかもしれません。

参考:
[Class Range  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

これに加えて、Web Appsを使用しているようであれば、スクリプトを変更した際はWeb Appsを新たなバージョンとして再デプロイしてください。これにより最新のスクリプトが反映されます。これにご注意ください。

---

*この投稿は @Tanaike さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*